# Can Azure WebSite+SQL Database be used as platform for a WAMP app like Moodle?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am wondering if it's sensible to try to install a fairly standard PHP app (it is Moodle, https://moodle.org) on Windows Azure?

Moodle is a pretty standard PHP app, which lives most happily on LAMP stack of Ubuntu + Apache + MySql + PHP5. I could use Azure to host a Linux VM with that stack, but I'm wondering if it is possible/advisable to instead install Moodle by using a combination of an Azure "Web Site" (which run PHP), and an Azure "SQL Database" (which would run the db).

My guess is this won't work, because the prepackaged Azure services are different on almost every point. I don't know if the Azure Web Sites run on Windows, or Linux, but I'm guessing Windows. I don't know if they're served by Apache or IIS, but I'm guessing IIS. I don't know if the Azure SQL Database is mysql or MS SQL Server, but I'm guessing the latter. Presumably these are all serious problems that make it either impossible or else deeply inadvisable.

So all of this makes it seem like the combination of an Azure "Web Site" + "SQL Database" is actually a terrible choice for a PHP app expecting LAMP. Is that correct?

I'm unfamiliar with PHP and web apps generally, so my apologies if this is a basic question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Web Sites are IIS on Windows. The SQL databases are MSSQL, but there is a MySQL option with ClearDB (though by default they'll only give you a 20MB database until you pay for extra room).

Your biggest issue isn't getting Moodle running on Azure, though, but in storing your moodledata directory. You have 1GB of space on the 'C' drive, and that's it. Using a Storage Blob to expand that space is going to require you modifying Moodle pre-installation.

In my view the only benefit of using Azure Web Sites over a VM is the automated scaling, letting you keep your costs down during low use periods. Since the data on 'C' isn't available to the other instances that are spun up, you can't make use of that feature.

If you want a cheap, fire-up on demand, cloud hosted Moodle test-bed, though, Azure Web Sites and ClearDB work pretty well.

Comment: Azure Sql databases aren't going to work as Moodle needs access to system indexes which isn't available in the hosted environment. So ClearDB is a good alternative if you want to stay on Azure Websites and use a DB service provider.